Sicstus CLPFD labeling time discrepancy
I was using Sicstus Prolog to solve Advent of Code 2024 Day 13, and I came across a surprising discrepancy in labeling times between different instances of the same constraint model. I have:
minCost(Ax, Bx, P, A, B) :-
    A in 0..sup, B in 0..sup,
    P #= A*Ax + B*Bx,
    Cost #= A+B,
    labeling([minimize(Cost)], [A,B,Cost]) -> true; (A=nil, B=nil).

Most instances of this, SAT or UNSAT, are done under 1 miliseconds. For example:
?- minCost(27, 60, 100003443, A, B).
A = 9,
B = 1666720 ? 

With fd_statistics showing:
Time:0, Resumps:148, Entailmnts:8, Prunings:157, Backtracks:1, Constrnts:4 

But some instances, around 10% of the data set from AoC Day 13, again SAT or UNSAT, take a huge amount of time. For example, this takes almost 3 seconds:
minCost(48, 16, 100017648, A, B).
A = 2083701,
B = 0 ? 

With fd_statistics showing:
Time:2722, Resumps:25004424, Entailmnts:8334812, Prunings:27088128, Backtracks:0, Constrnts:4 

Note the 10^4-fold increase in resumptions and prunings. Also,  A is very high and B is very low, this is a pattern for slow SAT instances.
There are plenty slow UNSAT instances, too, for example:
minCost(18, 21, 100001860, A, B).
A = nil,
B = nil ? 

with fd_statistics showing:
Time:1273, Resumps:19047989, Entailmnts:2, Prunings:14285996, Backtracks:1, Constrnts:3

I took the same dataset to SWI Prolog's CLPZ, and in total it's faster than Sicstus but more importantly it doesn't have the same discrepancy. I tried a non-prolog solver, called Minion, which performed similar to SWI's CLPZ in total time, and didn't have this wide discrepancy.
My question is, is it normal for constraint solvers to have this much difference in solution times for even such small models? Maybe Sicstus's solver is optimized for small-ish numbers and these large integers are outside that scope? (Note that they're still smaller than Sicstus/CLPFD's largest supported integer). Or did I stumble upon a possible bug?
Note: I tried on Sicstus 4.7.1 and 4.9.0, same issue. The measurements above are from 4.9.0.

Plz add the version you are using.

Just did, thanks!

Doesn't Sicstus have a bug tracker? This should be a bug ticket, not a stackoverflow question (yet)

I am wondering if this could be considered normal behaviour. Each solver has its own heuristics, etc that may come with tradeoffs. It may not be a bug. But if nobody weighs in here of course I could try with Sicstus themselves.
